# CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex returns nil

Tags: ios, pdf, uiimage, cgimage

I'm trying to convert a pdf file to an image with this solution :

```
CFURLRef urlRef = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"http://uat.okitoo.fr/document/document/s595_506cb1811852f/o_specimen-page-seule.pdf"];
CGImageSourceRef src = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(urlRef, NULL);
NSDictionary* options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:(id)[NSNumber numberWithInt:500] forKey:(id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize];
CGImageRef firstPage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(src, 0, (CFDictionaryRef)options);
UIImage* imagePDF = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:firstPage];
CGImageRelease(firstPage);
```

My pdf file is ok but when I try this code, the image doesn't appear and I have this message : ": ImageIO: CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex image source parameter is nil". I can't understand..

I tried with other links but I have the same problem..

Any ideas ?
Is there an other way to convert my pdf file to an image ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the incorrect API to create the URL, you need URLWithString:

```
CFURLRef urlRef = (CFURLRef)[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://uat.okitoo.fr/document/document/s595_506cb1811852f/o_specimen-page-seule.pdf"];
```

The API you are currently using is for urls to files on your local file system.

Comment: You made my day ! What a beginner mistake ! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Sebastien you now see why we needed the real code in your question to help you and wouldn't be able to with your original question…

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, your `urlRef` is probably `nil`.

Probably because you didn't mention the real full path but only the file name, and it can't find the file.

If your PDF is a file inside your application bundle, use `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"pdf"]`. If you downloaded it at runtime to some place in your  sandbox, simply use the path to where the PDF has been downloaded.

Comment: My pdf file isn't really "test.pdf", I just wrote this as an example. I correct it with the good path.

Comment: You can also see with the url that the link send you to a good pdf file, so where is the problem ?

Comment: The problem is that I can't have guessed that you didn't show your real code in your question and had to suppose that you used the actual path and tested the URL. You should explain that and what you tried to fix the code in your question, we can't guess it.

Comment: I know and I'm sorry for it. I edit my question with the real code and a better explanation, can you help me ?